# How to delete input text with Puppeteer

Tags: automation, puppeteer

I need to remove/delete text in an iFrame via puppeteer.  I can do it easily using the page method/object, i.e.

```
await page.click(cssSelectorInput);
for (let i = 0; i < settings._30; i++) {
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
}
```

The above will remove 30 characters or less from the CSS Selector cssSelectorInput.
But, when I try:

```
// Get the iFrame in Signle Sign On page
const frameHandle = await page.$('iframe[id="sso-iframe"]');
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();

await frame.click(cssSelectorInput);
for (let i = 0; i < settings._30; i++) {
    await frame.keyboard.press('Backspace');
}
```

Yes, I know, looking at the puppeteer, frame.keyboard is not there.  So, how can I remove text from an input box via puppeteer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems OK:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <iframe src='data:text/html,<input value="Text">'></iframe>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  await page.frames()[1].click('input');
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
  }
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Comment: Yea, I don't see that working for me.  I'm based on a frameHandle and can't use the 'page' approach.  I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work.  Any ideas how to use frameHandle with keyboard input?

Comment: I'll add my frame handle to my code above.

Comment: If you get the frame handle via `page.$()` why can't you use the same `page` for `page.keyboard.press()` later?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the keyboard methods are based on https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/ . There are no frame or element targets mentioned there, so maybe keyboard interface is global for a whole page and the browser may dispatch the event to focused frame and element automatically. Your issue may have another cause. Try to provide a code that reproduces the issue or describe it in more details.

Comment: Okay this worked - you're brilliant.  I had a separate  issue that prevented the above suggestion from being executed, but once I cleared that hurdle, it work perfectly.  Thank you @vsemozhebuty!